# Rails garbage collect is not removing old objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, garbage-collection

Some odd behavior I encountered while optimizing a rails view:

After tweaking the amount of garbage collect calls in a request I didnt see real improvements on the performance. Investigating the problem I found out garbage collect didn't really remove that much dead objects!

I got a very heavy view with LOADS of objects.
Using [scrap](https://github.com/cheald/scrap) I found out after a fresh server start and page load the amount of objects was about 670.000, after reloading the page 3 times the amount has risen to 19.000.000!
RAILS_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT is set to 16.000.000 and I can read GC has been called 1400 times.
Why does the memory keep increasing on a refresh of the page? And is there a way to make sure the old objects are removed by GC?

PS: Running on REE 1.8.7 2011.03 with rails 3.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommended to use newrelic for optimalization, got way more performance boost there then with a little gc tweaking..

You dont need to gc objects you never create :)